# Power Automate send email to user when new item added to sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have a Power Automate flow I am building to send an email to a user as confirmation when they have added a new item to a sharepoint list. The email needs to be sent from a shared mailbox.

1. I have connected the sharepoint site and selected the list I want
   the flow to connect to.
2. The 'Get my profile' step is set to get the
   profile of the user that created the item.
3. The Send email step is setup to send the email From a shared mailbox that only I have access too.

The issue I am having is that when a user other than myself creates an item in the sharepoint list and this flow runs, will the email send to the user from the shared mailbox if the user that created the item does not have access to the shared mailbox? I tried this on a similar flow using power apps for clicking a button and sending an email and I got an error saying that the user that triggered the flow does not have permission to send on behalf of the shared mail box and the flow failed.

Not sure what I might be doing wrong.

[image]